# Onboard ethernet stopped working after CPU/memory upgrade

Tags: ethernet

After CPU and memory upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 would not connect to router. It is a dual boot system and the win/xp sys Ethernet still works. I tried upgrading to 14.04, but still no Ethernet. The system sees the card (eth0) in the network connections tool, and reports 'last used' at xx minutes ago. That time being at boot up. There is an antenna icon at the top menu bar that is repeatedly cycling indicating it is searching for a connection like a wireless card will do. After a minute a message box pops up saying 'no network connection'. There is no wireless card installed in this desktop system. The network card also did not work during a liveCD session. I have also flashed the latest bios. I went from an AMD quad core to an 8 core processor and from DDR2 800 TO DDR3 1600 memory. No other hardware change.
Any ideas out there??

Answer (score 0):

Another day of searching for an answer has been successful. The following thread provided a fix. You may have to look through some of the comments at the end to find the correct location for the script to be added based on what version OS install you have. I have no clue why the CPU/memory upgrade triggered this, again everything was ok before.
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2020571.html